# Normal subgroup of a join

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group with subgroups $H$ and $K$ such that $H^K = \langle aHa^{-1} \, | a \in K \rangle = H$. Suppose that $x \in G$ such that $H^x = H^y$ for some $y \in \langle H, H^x \rangle$. I need to show that $H \unlhd \langle HK, (HK)^x \rangle$.

From $H^K = H$, we get that $K \leq N_G(H)$, and so $HK \leq N_G(H)$. Hence $H \unlhd HK$. If I can show that $(HK)^x \leq N_G(H)$, then I would be done. I can't seem to show this

Comment: Please explain the notation $H^K$.

Comment: $H^K = \langle aHa^{-1} \, | \, a \in K \rangle$ i.e the conjugate closure of $H$ in $K$

Comment: Why do you think that this is true?

Comment: It is part of proof of Lemma 2.2.2 from the research paper (http://elea.unisa.it/bitstream/handle/10556/174/tesi%20E.%20Romano.pdf;jsessionid=D01235B18288521A48173EC86277F659?sequence=1). The author just states this without elaborating. I'm not sure if I have left out any necessary details. Please have a look at the proof in the paper Prof. Derek Holt

Comment: I would think it is an error on the author's part

Comment: A counterexample is $G=S_3$, $K=1$, $H=\langle(1,2)\rangle$, $x=(2,3)$, where $\langle H,H^x \rangle = G$.